# Steps to install LAMP or XAMPP with phpmyadmin

Tags: php

What is the easiest way to install LAMP server for hosting PHP projects?
Previously on windows I used a XAMPP server. I have tried LAMP on LinuxMint, but the installation required to configure lot of files. So is there a small and easy way to do it, it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the site to be asking that question as it is not related to elementary OS itself.

To answer your question: The easiest way is to download Apache, PHP, MySQL || MariaDB and PHPMyAdmin directly from the repos. This can be easily achieved by typing `sudo apt install php5 mariadb-server phpmyadmin` in the terminal. This is the easiest and more customizable way to this.

For further reference [take a look at this Digital Ocean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04) on how to setup LAMP on Ubuntu enviroments.